# Coding NFC-chip in C and other NFC-questions

Tags: c, nfc

Bear with me on this, I'm new to the NFC technology and also fairly new to coding.

So I have a small pet project of mine for my studies that I would like to use NFC technology to achieve. I have a device that measures gas pressure in a pipe. It does daily logs of how much gas was used and other relevant information, so I guess you can say it is a gas meter of sorts. The idea is that I want an NFC chip incorporated into the existing device, so that I can tap my phone to it and receive lets say the latest daily log.

My question is then: **how do I program the chip that I incorporate into the existing gas meter?** I have read tons and tons of articles and still find that I'm unsure of how to program the chip if I cannot use an app for it. I did download some apps that can code NFC tags, and I also bought some tags and managed to code one to turn on my PC for me and another to set my phone to silent when tapped. So I can use the apps just fine, but I think what I want to achieve with the meter is beyond what the apps can do for me.

So, the course for which I'm working on this project does 90% of coding in C, so I would like to also do the actual coding in C if that is possible. If not, what language do you code NFC in?

Also, how do I get the code onto the chip? Do I need some sort of writer/reader type thing?

Any input is appreciated, and I apologise if this has been asked before. I searched the website, but I didn't find anything that really answered my questions.

Comment: You don't need an NFCtag. You can use an NFC reader that you program to operate in target mode (i.e. pretend to be an NFC tag). Have a look at the libnfc for software that can help you with this.

Comment: You don't want to be pushing a large amount of data over NFC, Mifare tags can only do 1-4k, and a secure element is slow. Wouldn't it be easier to make those logs accessible over a network somehow, and then use a tag with a simple link on it? The use-case is pretty much the same (tap a tag, see logs), but you're using NFC in a very simple way.

Comment: James, you have a point there. Maybe have the tag initiate the connection  and then let the wifi/bluetooth/network do the actual data transfer? I will read more into this.

Comment: FUZxxl: Thanks! I'll read more into the NFC readers. i have come across the term but never really understood what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple data-logger application like this a full blown NFC transceiver chip is likely overkill.

You're probably fine if you use one of the dual interface eeprom chips like the M24LR64-R. To the microcontroller they look just like a ordinary I²C eeprom. Reading and writing them is done using a very simple protocol.

From the NFC side they show up as a ISO15683 tag, and you can read the eeprom content back using the NfcV.transceive method. Again a simple protocol is used. All that is documented in the data-sheet.

There are other chips with the same capability from other manufacturers. I just recommended the M24LR64-R because I have first-hand experience with them and they work flawless.